# Laravel: How to use a separate template for each user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have many landing pages template and I want save all templates (layouts) name on database. How I get layout name from database and extend. For example I have sample database structure:

```
Table `users`
Table `themes`
Table `configurations`
```

On table users and themes have user datas and themes name. And table `configurations` have sample structure:

```
id
user_id
theme_id
```

How I can get theme name from `configurations` table then extend needed layout from `views` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on relationships you're using. The good choice here is to use many-to-many I guess. Get the template name, for example:

```
$template = Theme::whereHas('users', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    })
    ->value('name');
```

Then pass the variable to a view and extend it like this:

```
@extends($template)
```